# Right way for text inside math

Tags: math-mode, formatting, text-mode

I'd like to know (if there is) the better way to **punctuate text** inside math mode. I mean, when we use `,` or `;`, they are punctuation for the text, not for the math and so **I think** that they **should** be typed with the same font used for the text.

Consider the (non sense) example below. Please, note the font for `,` and the way I inserted blank space after it inside the sets.

Which one would you use?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[a5paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{thm}Statement here in italic font. Then:
\begin{align*}
a_n&=
    \begin{cases}
        n+1, & \text{for odd $n$},\\
        n+2, & \text{for even $n$}.
    \end{cases}
\\[1ex]
a_n&=
    \begin{cases}
        n+1, & \text{for odd $n$,}\\
        n+2, & \text{for even $n$.}
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Also, let 
$ A=  \{a_n,\ \text{for any $n>30$}\} $, 
$ A'= \{a_n,  \text{ for any $n>40$}\} $ and 
$ A''=\{a_n   \text{, for any $n>50$}\} $.
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How about `Also, let $ A=  \{a_n$ for any $n>30\}$` ?

Comment: @Holene, this is not a good idea. It will not work for displaystyle, for example.

Comment: I would use `\textnormal` instead of `\text`.

Comment: @Mico, I checked the definition of `\textnormal` now but I can not see what would change. Is it simple to have an example?

Comment: Assuming the "normal" text font (outside the theorem-like environment...) is an upright roman font, `\textnormal` will render its argument in the same upright roman font. If the "normal" text font is an upright sans-serif, `\textnormal` will pick up on that too.

Comment: @Sigur - I voted to close this posting based on the part of your question related to the `\text` instruction. If your posting is really more about the placement of puctuation marks, please let me know and I'll vote to reopen to the posting.

Comment: @Mico, I was reading the post you cited but it is not the same. My problem is where to insert the commas: in math or text mode. Also, the spaces after them: using `\` in math mode or blank spaces in text mode? Please, could you reopen it?

Comment: @Sigur - I've reopened the posting. You may want to edit it a bit to remove any ambiguity as to what the posting is about -- I suspect I'm not the only one who got stuck on the suboptimal use of `\text`.

Comment: I consider something like `$A= \{a_n,\ \text{for any $n>30$}\}$` simply wrong notation; `$A=\{a_n:n>30\}$` would be right.

Comment: @egreg, I agree. It was only a dummy example. What I need is to write some textual parts inside some math contents, since it would be complicated to write using only symbols.

Comment: I'd probably write  `$A=\{\text{$a_n$, for any $n > 30$}\}$`

Comment: @egreg, what about the comma after `n+1`? Should it be in italic?

Comment: in "traditional" (i.e., metal) math composition, all punctuation in theorems was upright, so it would be uniform whether in a math or a text context.  there really should be a "theorem" font set up in this way, but that is a real pain, and it has never been done.